# Why returning string is not printing in C++

Tags: c++

I am having an issue with my C++ code. I am learning C++. I have written a C++ code for deleting a character from a string. My code is running without an error but not getting a output.

My Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string deletion(string s, int position) {
  string newS;                                    
  int i = 0, j = 0, sLen = s.length();
  while(sLen != 0) {
    if(i != position) {   
      newS[j] = s[i];
      j++;
    }
    i++;
    sLen--;
  }

  return newS;
}

int main() {
  cout << deletion("abcd", 2) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Why I am not getting any output? How to solve this problem?

Comment: If you're learning C++, do not tag your questions with the C tag too unless you are particularly fond of downvotes.  They are vastly different languages and what applies to strings in C++ does not apply in C and vice versa.

Comment: `newS[j] =` will be assigning out of bounds since you never resized `newS`, you should be using `+=`  or `push_back` or similar.

Comment: Instead of the loop, you could use `newS = s.substr(0, position) + s.substr(position+1);`

Comment: `newS[j] = s[i];` -- Change that to: `newS.at(j) = s[i];` -- Now what error do you get?  I bet it's an `std::out_of_range` exception, explaining why your code is faulty.

Comment: I must sound like a broken record but I really don't understand. Four downvotes, two close votes (for not reproducible or caused by a typo, both things clearly untrue). Yet this question is a perfect [mre]. Closed as a duplicate I could understand but this question is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: Sounds like you could just have `return s.erase(position);` if `position` is always in bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This string has zero length

```
string newS;
```

This code attempts to write a character to a zero length string

```
newS[j] = s[i];
```

That is an out of bounds error and therefore your code has undefined behaviour.

Here's your code rewritten so that it adds characters to the string.

```
string deletion(string s, int position) {
  string newS;                                    
  int i = 0, sLen = s.length();
  while(sLen != 0) {
    if(i != position) {   
      newS.push_back(s[i]);
    }
    i++;
    sLen--;
  }

  return newS;
}
```

I haven't checked the rest of the logic, but this code is clearly the code you were trying to write. You're not the first beginner to think that strings grow automatically when you write characters to them, but this is not true.